# Как сделать команду, по которой бот будет писать сообщение с реакцией, после нажатия которой пользователь будет получать роль?

Tags: python, discord.py

Требуется сделать команду, по которой бот будет писать сообщение с реакцией, после нажатия которой пользователь будет получать роль. Сделал так, чтобы бот ставил реакцию, но не могу сделать выдачу роли по нажатию.

````
URL = None
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36'}
RANK_ROLE = {
    'unranked': 783007655437271061,
    'COPPER V': 783004133741166602,
    'COPPER IV': 783004133741166602,
    'COPPER III': 783004133741166602,
    'COPPER II': 783004133741166602,
    'COPPER I': 783004133741166602,
    'BRONZE V': 783004192251838505,
    'BRONZE IV': 783004192251838505,
    'BRONZE III': 783004192251838505,
    'BRONZE II': 783004192251838505,
    'BRONZE I': 783004192251838505,
    'SILVER V': 783004251965489172,
    'SILVER IV': 783004251965489172,
    'SILVER III': 783004251965489172,
    'SILVER II': 783004251965489172,
    'SILVER I': 783004251965489172,
    'GOLD III': 783002165261631508,
    'GOLD II': 783002165261631508,
    'GOLD I': 783002165261631508,
    'PLATINUM III': 778502500453580840,
    'PLATINUM II': 778502500453580840,
    'PLATINUM I': 778502500453580840,
    'DIAMOND': 778502219208589352,
    'CHAMPION': 783006747027046410
}
RANK_IMG = {
    'unranked': 'https://i.imgur.com/sB11BIz.png',
    'COPPER V': 'https://i.imgur.com/B8NCTyX.png',
    'COPPER IV': 'https://i.imgur.com/ehILQ3i.jpg',
    'COPPER III': 'https://i.imgur.com/6CxJoMn.jpg',
    'COPPER II': 'https://i.imgur.com/eI11lah.jpg',
    'COPPER I': 'https://i.imgur.com/eI11lah.jpg',
    'BRONZE V': 'https://i.imgur.com/TIWCRyO.png',
    'BRONZE IV': 'https://i.imgur.com/42AC7RD.jpg',
    'BRONZE III': 'https://i.imgur.com/QD5LYD7.jpg',
    'BRONZE II': 'https://i.imgur.com/9AORiNm.jpg',
    'BRONZE I': 'https://i.imgur.com/hmPhPBj.jpg',
    'SILVER V': 'https://i.imgur.com/PY2p17k.png',
    'SILVER IV': 'https://i.imgur.com/D36ZfuR.jpg',
    'SILVER III': 'https://i.imgur.com/m8GToyF.jpg',
    'SILVER II': 'https://i.imgur.com/EswGcx1.jpg',
    'SILVER I': 'https://i.imgur.com/KmFpkNc.jpg',
    'GOLD III': 'https://i.imgur.com/B0s1o1h.jpg',
    'GOLD II': 'https://i.imgur.com/ELbGMc7.jpg',
    'GOLD I': 'https://i.imgur.com/ffDmiPk.jpg',
    'PLATINUM III': 'https://i.imgur.com/tmcWQ6I.png',
    'PLATINUM II': 'https://i.imgur.com/CYMO3Er.png',
    'PLATINUM I': 'https://i.imgur.com/qDYwmah.png',
    'DIAMOND': 'https://i.imgur.com/37tSxXm.png',
    'CHAMPION': 'https://i.imgur.com/VlnwLGk.png'
}
@bot.command()
async def reg(ctx, nick):
    global URL
    website = 'https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/'
    URL = website + nick
 
    def get_html(url):
        global HEADERS
        r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
        tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
        return r, tree
 
    def get_content(html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all('div', class_='trn-text--dimmed')
        img = soup.find('div', class_='trn-profile-header__avatar').find('img')
        wins_xpath = get_html(URL)[1].xpath('//*[@id="profile"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]')
        losses_xpath = get_html(URL)[1].xpath('//*[@id="profile"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]')
        kills_xpath = get_html(URL)[1].xpath('//*[@id="profile"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]')
        HS_chance_xpath = get_html(URL)[1].xpath('//*[@id="profile"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]')
        KD_xpath = get_html(URL)[1].xpath('//*[@id="profile"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]')
        KD = KD_xpath[0].text.strip('\n')
        HS_chance = HS_chance_xpath[0].text.strip('\n')
        kills = kills_xpath[0].text.strip('\n')
        losses = losses_xpath[0].text.strip('\n')
        wins = wins_xpath[0].text.strip('\n')
 
        ranks = []
        for item in items:
            title = item.get_text(strip=True)
            ranks.append({
                'title': title,
            })
 
        MMR = ranks[2]['title']
        TRANK = ranks[0]['title']
        return MMR, TRANK, img['src'], RANK_IMG[TRANK], wins, losses, HS_chance, KD, kills
 
    def parse():
        global URL
        html = get_html(URL)[0]
        if html.status_code == 200:
            print('Connect to website')
            mmr_rank = get_content(html.text)
            return mmr_rank
        else:
            print('Error')
    try:
        mmr_rank = parse()
        if mmr_rank[0] in mmr_rank:
            emb = discord.Embed(color=0xfab319)
            emb.set_author(name=nick, icon_url=mmr_rank[2])
            emb.add_field(name='```RANK```', value=f'```{mmr_rank[1]}```')
            emb.add_field(name='```MMR```', value=f'```{mmr_rank[0]}```', inline=False)
            emb.add_field(name='WINS', value=mmr_rank[4], inline=False)
            emb.add_field(name='LOSSES', value=mmr_rank[5], inline=False)
            emb.add_field(name='HEADSHOOTS CHANCE', value=mmr_rank[6], inline=False)
            emb.add_field(name='KILL/DEATH', value=mmr_rank[7], inline=False)
            emb.add_field(name='RANKED KILLS', value=mmr_rank[8], inline=False)
            emb.set_thumbnail(url = mmr_rank[3])
            mess = await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
            await mess.add_reaction('✅')
            message_id = mess.id
            @bot.event
            async def on_raw_reaction_add(ctx):
                message_id = mess.id
                print(ctx.user_id)
                if message_id == mess.id:  
                    guild_id = ctx.guild_id
                    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id,
                                               bot.guilds)
                    if ctx.emoji.name == "✅":
                        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, 
                                                 id=RANK_ROLE[mmr_rank[1]])
                        member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == 
                                                    ctx.user_id,
                                                    guild.members)
                        if member: 
                            await member.add_roles(role) 
                        else:
                            print('Такого челика нет')
                    else:
                        print("Такой роли нет")
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
````

Comment: @Эникейщик у вас русская клавиатура сломалась, или только буква `к`?

Comment: @Danis лениво переключаться было :)

Comment: щас пробелам в том что когда я нажимаю на реакцию в терминал пишет что меня не существует

Answer (score 1):

А что за бот. Для каких целей
Смотри как агента можно устанавливать.

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
```

Comment: так сказать универсал это одна из его функций с которой у меня проблемы